# Gnome tracker not indexing all music

Tags: fedora, gnome3

In Fedora 21 the gnome-tracker stops indexing music files after couple of minutes.

My music-library is about 60GB, but mostly due to a lot of flac-files converted from my CDs.

I tried

```
tracker-control --reset-hard
tracker-control --start
```

and monitored the system-performance. After about 5 minutes the cpu-usage consumed by the tracker-daemons drops to zero and nothing more is indexed. I always end up with the same albums displayed in Gnome Music Player, which makes me suspect that there is something causing the tracker to stop indexing the rest.

I had a look at tracker-preferences and all folders are configured as they should.

I could not find any log-files, nor error messages. Any hints where I can find those, or what might cause this behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but the limit is disabled and plenty of disc-space is available.

Comment: I see... In that case I advise you to read the official [debugging page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/Documentation/Debugging) and follow the instructions specific to the version of _tracker_ you are using. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the link provided by don_crissti, I found out that I was actually wrong about the commands.

the correct-commands for tracker-controll are the following

```
# reset    
tracker-control -r
#restart
tracker-control -s
```

But what was more interesting is **tracker-stats**

```
[xxx@yyy ~]$ tracker-stats 
Statistiken:
  nao:Tag = 1
  nco:Contact = 3
  nfo:Audio = 11095
  nfo:Document = 79
  nfo:Executable = 123
  nfo:FileDataObject = 14778
  nfo:Folder = 1115
  nfo:Image = 2222
  nfo:Media = 13317
  nfo:MediaList = 136
  nfo:PaginatedTextDocument = 4
  nfo:PlainTextDocument = 75
  nfo:TextDocument = 79
  nmm:MusicPiece = 11095
  nmm:Photo = 2111
  nmm:Playlist = 57
  rdfs:Class = 235
  rdfs:Resource = 16203
  tracker:Volume = 1
```

According to this, **all my files have been scanned**, so I checked the musicplayer again. After looking at the "Titles"-Tab I saw that 80% of the tracks have no metadata. Well, they do, but **the ID3-Tags are obviously not recognized** and when I remember right, my files are tagged with ID3 V2 metadata.

I couldnt find any reports about the tracker not being able to read that format but it definitely looks like that.

Comment: as noted in the provided debugging page [link](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/Documentation/Debugging), the hyphenated commands changed, if you're able to do so you can update your answer:
`tracker reset (-r|--hard) (-e|--soft)`

`tracker daemon (-s|--start) (-t|--terminate) (-k|--kill)`

`tracker status --stat`

Answer (score 0):

If the tracker doesn't pick up music files, it's best to first check where `grep XDG_MUSIC ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` points to (see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1247752/191702)), correct it and then trigger reindexing by either terminating and restarting the daemon

```
tracker daemon --terminate
tracker daemon --start
```

or resetting the path (works recursively on directories)

```
tracker reset --file <path>
```

`tracker daemon --watch` will show new entries while scanning.

If you look at the output of `tracker status --stat`, you can query [higher class objects](https://developer.gnome.org/ontology/stable/nie-DataObject.html) to verify how many objects the index contains for a given subfolder:

```
tracker sql -q 'select count("nie:url") from "nie:DataObject" where "nie:url" like "%/Music/%";'
```

and compare to `find ~/Music/ -type f | wc -l`